# Why would the loss stop decreasing after certain number of epoch in PyTorch training loop?

Tags: pytorch

I am training a model in PyTorch and have set the number of epoch to `80`.

Initially the loss value was decreasing (indicating the model is learning):

```
Epoch: 8|Loss:0.17129679024219513
Epoch:16|Loss:0.10746248811483383
Epoch:22|Loss:0.05994463711977005
Epoch:26|Loss:0.02823618240654468
Epoch:32|Loss:0.03788195922970772 <-- training stalls, loss stops decreasing
Epoch:54|Loss:0.03788195922970772
Epoch:64|Loss:0.03788195922970772
...snip...
Epoch:72|Loss:0.03788195922970772
Epoch:76|Loss:0.03788195922970772
Epoch:78|Loss:0.03788195922970772
```

You can see that after epoch 32 the loss stops decreasing. Can someone explain why this might be happening?

The main part of my code for training:

```
torch.manual_seed(87)

epoch=80

for epochs in range(epoch):
    model_0.train()
    Y_pred=model_0(X_train)
    loss=Loss(Y_pred,Y_train)
    Optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    print(f"Loss:{loss}")

    Optimizer.step()
    model_0.eval()

    with torch.inference_mode():
        test_pred=model_0(X_test)
        test_loss=Loss(test_pred,Y_test)

    if epochs % 2== 0:
        print (f"Epoch:{epochs}|Loss:{loss}|Test loss:{test_loss}")
        with torch.inference_mode():
            Y_preds_new=model_0(X_test)
            plot_predictions(predictions=Y_preds_new);
            print (model_0.state_dict())
```

Comment: Assuming your code has no bug, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352037